# Clojure: defprotocol, default implementaion, not inlined

Tags: clojure

### Edit

This question makes no sense because I'm an idiot and misread the Clojure documentation.

### What I have:

I have something like this:

```
(defprotocol Foo "doc" [foo bar]
  (Foo-bark [foo])
  (Foo-meow [foo])
  (Foo-other [foo]
     ... long
     multi
     line
     inline
     implementation))
```

### What I would prefer:

```
(defprotocol Foo "doc" [foo bar]
  (Foo-bark [foo])
  (Foo-mewo [foo])
  (Foo-other [foo]))

(define Foo-other [foo]
   .. long
   multi
    line
   implementation)
```

### Question

Is the above possible? If not, what is the closest I can get to it?

Comment: Are you trying to implement the protocol function in the protocol definition itself?

Comment: I am currently implementing the protocol function inside of the protocol definition itself. I would prefer to not do it that way as it hinders readability when I just want to scan _what_ the functions are without caring _how_ they are implemented.

Comment: defprotocol can't be used to provide implementations for its functions/methods. You need to use deftype or reify to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

defprotocol can't be used to provide implementations for its functions/methods. You need to use deftype or reify or extend / extend-type (or drop down to classes to do that. For your use-case, you can use `extend` to refer to earlier-defined functions to implement a protocol.